# java Jbutton array preventing constructor from finishing running

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, jbutton

So I want to create a program that creates a JPanel window with 8 JButtons. instead of repeating the JButtons, I just made an array with all of the JButtons and made a loop to create them. Ever since I made an array however, the constructor will not proceed after the loop finishes. This never happened until I made the JButtons into an array.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

private JButton Subject[] = new JButton[7];
private String SubjNames[] = {"Length", "Mass", "Currency", "Temperature", "Time", "Speed", "Data", "Cooking"};

private int SubjectLocX = 40;
private int SubjectLocY = 50;




public Gui (){

    super("Converter");
    setLayout(null);

    System.out.println("yes");

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Subject[i] = new JButton(SubjNames[i]);
    Subject[i].setLocation(SubjectLocX,SubjectLocY);
    Subject[i].setSize(200,50);
    add(Subject[i]);
    if (i < 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 40;
        SubjectLocY += 100;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        SubjectLocY = 50;
    } else if (i > 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 330;
        SubjectLocY += 100;
        }
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,500);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

Yes, I imported everything needed and I created an object of the class in a seperate class. It will run, but the constructor will not continue after the loop. If you remove the lines with the array "Subject[i]", the constructor finishes and the window appears, but with the array, it does not. Why??

Comment: Remember, when you declare an array as `new JButton[7]` means you've only allocated 7 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you have a JButton array with 7 elements and you are tring to initialize 8 of them. Change declaration with `private JButton Subject[] = new JButton[8]` and you will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is workinf for me, you just had an array out of bounds in the "for" loop, the condition has to be `for (int i = 0; i<7; i++)` but everything else is working, remember to call "`new Gui().setVisible(true);`"